# Sum reversed Arrays on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Supposing I have the following situation on mongodb:

```
{
  "_id" : 654321,
  "first_name" : "John",
  "demand" : [1, 20, 4, 10 ],
  "group" : [1, 2]
}

{
  "_id" : 654321,
  "first_name" : "Bert",
  "demand" : [4, 10 ],
  "group" : [1, 3]
}
```

1 - Is it possible to groupby based on the first index of "group" array ([1]) ?

2- Is it possible to reverse the index order, and sum those demand arrays vertically ?

**Desired output:**

1 - Select only `group.0 : 1`

2 - reverse the array order `$reverseArray`

```
[1, 20, 4, 10 ] -> [10, 4, 20, 1] (reversed)
[4, 10] -> [10, 4] (reversed)
```

3 - Sum (vertical axis)

```
[20, 8, 20, 1]
```

Finally, return the normal order:

```
[1, 20, 8, 20]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - Is it possible to groupby based on the first index of "group"
>   array ([1]) ?

To get the first index position (i.e., `0`; array indexes start from `0`) use the `$arrayElemAt` aggregation operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $group: { _id: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$group", 0 ] } } }, ] )
```

> 2- Is it possible to reverse the index order, and sum those demand
>   arrays vertically ?

You can reverse an array using the `$reverseArray` aggregation array operator.

To get the sum of values of each array's element position, (i) get the index of each value with unwind, and finally (ii) group by the index and sum the values.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          demand: { $reverseArray: "$demand" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $unwind: { path: "$demand", includeArrayIndex: "ix" }
  },
  { 
      $group: {
           _id: "$ix", 
           sum: { $sum: "$demand" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $sort: { _id: 1 }    // this is optional; sorts by index position
  }
] )
```